# C# HTTP get response headers are missing

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-headers, response

I am trying to make a HTTP get request in C# and get it's headers, because one of them is important for my application.

I can see with Wireshark, that the headers are arrived properly.

My application looks like this:

```
HttpWebRequest wrGETURL = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
wrGETURL.Method = "HEAD";
wrGETURL.Headers.Add("UserServerIdent", "2");
WebResponse response = wrGETURL.GetResponse();
for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.GetKey(i));
}
```

It lists these headers only: Vary, Content-Type, Date, Server, X-Powered-By

However in WireShark I can see Location and some others too.

Do anyone know why I can't see the other headers? Or maybe I should try to get the headers in some other ways?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

did you tried fiddler web debugger?

http://fiddler2.com

there you can also see headers and much more..

Comment: Ah now I can see that it redirects me to an other location. So I may get the headers of that location.

Comment: Ah yes.. as I set the AllowAutoRedirect property of the HttpWebRequest object to false, then I got the headers that I needed. Funny that I've also written Location header in my question and didn't think that it will then redirect.